# Create check_box from database on view using each and puts value and id

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to display one checkbox for every id that comes from the database could help me, following my code tried but is displaying more than 1 checkbox in the same  check_box = "id: 1", check_box "id: 2"

I want to display this way

```
<td> check_box="id1" value="false"</td> 
<td> check_box="id2" value="true"</td>
```

**i want too this if one check_box 
this checked on submit form on rails console puts:**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b3kaOUAgyJHqho70958585SVSv7a1Eo3Yd2z54=", "@search_inactive"=>"30","true"}

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b3kaOUAgyJHqho70958585Sassaffdaaz=", "@search_inactive"=>"29","false"}
```

**My View:**

```
<tr>
<td>
 <%= link_to "Answer", "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1WdpuW2pD-bqhlSmC77sWb3_nz56NAF-kHSh5--GkLnY/edit", :target => "_blank", :class => "btn_forms_gf" %>
  <td align="center">
  <%= form_for :app_changes, :url => {:controller => :user, :action => :show_search } do |f| %>
  <% @search_inactive.each do |p| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "@search_inactive", {}, p.id %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_function('Disable', "$('form').submit()", :app_changes => @show_search, :class => "btn_save") %>
  <% end %>
  </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**My Controller to render page with all searchs inactives and actives**

```
     def show_search
       @show_search_active = Search.find_by_sql("select * from search where active is true")
       @show_search_inactive = Search.find_by_sql("select * from search where active is false")
   render('/users/show_search_users', :layout => true)
   end
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935467/nested-checkboxes-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to setup your form with both a `hidden_field_tag` and a `checkbox_tag` for each checkbox input:

```rb
<%= form_for ...%>
  <% @search_inactive.each do |p| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "search_inactive[#{p.id}]", false %>
    <%= check_box_tag "search_inactive[#{p.id}]", true %> 
  <% end %>

  <% @search_active.each do |p| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "search_active[#{p.id}]", false %>
    <%= check_box_tag "search_active[#{p.id}]", true, true %> # true here to have it checked by default 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now when you submit your form the params will look like:

```rb
{
  "search_inactive"=>{"2"=>"false", "4"=>"false", "71"=>"false", "72"=>"false", "73"=>"false", "74"=>"false"},
  "search_active"=>{"102"=>"true", "104"=>"true", "171"=>"true", "172"=>"true", "173"=>"true", "174"=>"true"}
}
```

The extra `hidden_field_tag` allows the form to submit `false` when the checkbox is NOT checked. But, if the checkbox is checked by a user in the UI the form will submit `true`. This is a trick that [Rails usually does for you automatically when generating a form](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), but since you're building out the form yourself you need to include the hidden tag explicitly.